# Resolving SQL "The network path was not found" error

Tags: sql, visual-studio, iis, networking, ms-access-2010

I have built a very small ASP.NET site using MS Access 2010 as the database, which works in test mode. This is for an offline intranet application, so I'm not concerned about security - hardware access is the route for hacking here. This is all being built in VS WebExpress 2012.

When I try to publish to IIS 7.5, open the website's splash page and then proceed to page two, I'm being given two top-tier error messages:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]

My connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\PersonalArt Version 0055.accdb";Persist Security Info=True
```

I don't know why this is creating a SQL Server error, as I'm not trying to use SQL Server.

I've tried looking into the SQL Server side of things [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/). I have checked that SQL Server is running, that SQL Browser is enabled and running, and that the appropriate ports are open in the firewall.

I have added a connection string to IIS 7.5 that at least points to `ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, but I cannot remove the default connection string for SQL Server Express.

I've looked [here](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/what-should-my-connection-string-look-like.html) about the construction of connection strings, and I've seen instructions about removing bad connections strings and replacing them [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1454592.aspx) (but I'm afraid of this because I don't understand it).

I intend to use a WIFI tablet controller, and I've established that IIS is working well enough that I can see an index page on the controller.

So I've been bouncing around trying to figure out if this is an IIS problem, a SQL install/manage problem, or a firewall/security problem.

Comment: Are you using `System.Data.SqlClient` objects and methods to try and connect to the Access database? If so, then try using the corresponding `System.Data.OleDb` gizmos instead.

Comment: Gordon, thanks- But I'm not using either, at least not knowingly. I've been working under the very naive idea that everything I do in test mode should migrate transparently to the website.  Are you thinking this belongs in the config file?  somewhere on each webpage?  I need a little more to work with here.

Answer (score 1):

**For Error 0x80004005:**

**Idea #1**: try removing the double quotes around the directory listing and re-test your code (I mention this even though you may have already tried it):

```
"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\PersonalArt Version 0055.accdb"
```

**Idea #2**: The error does say **The network path was not found**. Try creating a local share and give the IIS account at least read permissions to that share changing the directory listing to something like

```
\\MyServer\MyShare\PersonalArt Version 0055.accdb
```

**Idea: #3:** As a DBA I do cater towards SQL Server so I'd personally try testing the connection string itself to see if it does return data--using SQL Server. If it doesn't work here, I wouldn't expect it to work with ASP.NET either:

Try running this within SQL Server to see if you even get data back querying  to a table name within Access (unless you have a better way to test the connection string):

```
SELECT * FROM  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\PersonalArt Version 0055.accdb";Persist Security Info=True, 'SELECT * FROM <your table>')
```

But before you do, you may need to run the following in SQL Server so it recognizes ACE.OLEDB.12.0 and distributed queries:

```
exec sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 
GO
```

**For SqlException (0x80131904):**

The SQL error sounds like another issue altogether. Try enabling SQL for remote connectivity on the **production** SQL box (or wherever production is connecting) within SQL Server Configuration Manager:

[image]